# position of an element has to be in increasing order

Tags: xslt

I want my XSLT to find the position of the element in an increasing order like 1,2,3,4,5 etc., but my xslt generates position as 1,2,4,5,8.

XML

```
<tags>
   <tag>
     <display>Yes</display>
     <data>position<data>
   </tag>
   <tag>
     <display>Yes</display>
     <data>position<data>
   </tag>
   <tag>
     <display>No</display>
     <data>position<data>
   </tag>
   <tag>
     <display>No</display>
     <data>position<data>
   </tag>
   <tag>
     <display>Yes</display>
     <data>position<data>
   </tag>
</tags>
```

XSLT

```
  <xsl:for-each select="tags/tag">
    <xsl:if test="display[contains(text(),'Yes')]">
      <xsl:value-of select="data"/> - <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Expected Output:
     i want my position to be displayed like :

```
position - 1
position - 2
position - 3
```

Actual Output:

```
position - 1
position - 2
position - 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position()` will be based on the tags you initially select in the `xsl:for-each`, and you are selecting all 5 tags to start with.

Instead, add your if condition as a condition in the `xsl:for-each` instead, so you only select the 3 you need, and so the position will be 1, 2, 3 as required

```
<xsl:for-each select="tags/tag[display[contains(text(),'Yes')]]">
  <xsl:value-of select="data"/> - <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or, you could simplify the `xsl:for-each` to this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="tags/tag[contains(display,'Yes')]">
```